# Регистры ввода-выводы. ATmega 8535

Tags: микроконтроллеры

Есть регистры PORTA, PORTB і т. д. К ним можно обращаться по имени или по адресу. Вопрос: как узнать адреса этих регистров (в даташите не нашел, может плохо смотрел)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В даташите на контроллер стр.299 адреса регистров:
0x1B (0x3B) PORTA
0x18 (0x38) PORTB

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).